# Python code to check if a input string can be written with a single row of keyboard(eg:potter,flash)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to write a Python code to check if the given word can be typed using just a single row of the keyboard (e.g. POTTER, EQUITY). Print 'Yes' if the letters of the word are from a single row and print 'No' otherwise.

Here is my code (not getting desired output)

```
row1='qwertyuiop'
row2='asdfghjkl'
row3='zxcvbnm'
i=0
j=0
status='no'
st=input('enter a string : ')
if st[0] in row1:
    while(i<len(st)):
        while(j<len(row1)):
            if(st[i]==row1[j]):
                status='yes'
                i+=1
                j=0

            elif(j==(len(st)-1)):
                 status='no'
                 break
            else:
                j+=1
    j=0
    i=0

elif st[0] in row2:
     while(i<len(st)):
        while(j<len(row2)):
            if(st[i]==row2[j]):
                status='yes'
                i+=1
                j=0

            elif(j==(len(st)-1)):
                 status='no'
                 break
            else:
                j+=1
    j=0
    i=0
else: 
    while(i<len(st)):
        while(j<len(row3)):
            if(st[i]==row3[j]):
                status='yes'
                i+=1
                j=0

            elif(j==(len(st)-1)):
                 status='no'
                 break
            else:
                j+=1    
print(status)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I added in some handling for uppercase, numbers and special characters:

```
def keyboard_test(string, ignore_unk = True):
    string = string.lower()
    rows = ['qwertyuiop','asdfghjkl','zxcvbnm']
    # rows = ['!@#$%^&*()_+1234567890-=','qwertyuiop[]\\{}|','asdfghjkl;:"'+"'",'zxcvbnm,<.>/?']
    key_dict = {}
    for index, row in enumerate(rows):
        for i in row:
            if i in string:
                key_dict[i] = index

    string_char_rows = [key_dict[i] if i in key_dict else "Unk" for i in string]
    if ignore_unk:
        string_char_rows = [i for i in string_char_rows if i != "Unk"]

    # return len(set(string_char_rows)) <= 1 # returns True/False, likely more useful

    if len(set(string_char_rows)) <= 1:
        return "Yes"
    return "No"
```

return Yes if they're all in one line

```
keyboard_test("EQUITY")

Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sets, this can be done efficiently.

The set of characters in the input must be the subset of some row.

```
def writable_in_one_line(word):
    rows = (
         set('qwertyuiop'),
         set('asdfghjkl'),
         set('zxcvbnm'))

    chars = set(word.lower())

    return any(chars <= row for row in rows)
```

### Example

```
word = input('Word: ')

print('Yes' if writable_in_one_line(word) else 'No')
```

### Output

```
Word: POTTER
Yes
```

If, as you mentionned, you are not allowed to use `set` in your class. Then there is a less performant solution using only strings.

```
def writable_in_one_line(word):
    rows = (
         'qwertyuiop',
         'asdfghjkl',
         'zxcvbnm')

    chars = word.lower()

    return any(all(c in row for c in chars) for row in rows)
```

Comment: Thank you,but currently im a student and im allowed to use only string concepts :)

Comment: @Pro_Noob I added the equivalent solution using strings only.